# Cufon fonts messed up on site in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, cufon

They definitely looked OK a couple days ago, not sure what changed.

Please check http://www.totaltab.com - the header text looks all messed up in my Chrome for some reason. Firefox is just fine.

I read the grainy look can be attributed to hardware acceleration being turned on in about:flags but I don't even see that option available any more. I'm wondering if Chrome released a new version that updated that by default includes the acceleration?

A link mentioning hardware acceleration: http://groups.google.com/group/cufon/browse_thread/thread/dd58651c79323482?pli=1

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I'm running the latest development Chrome on Linux, and it looks fine to me.

Comment: Added - thanks for that, didn't even think of a screenshot. I'm 99.9% sure I didn't change anything recently.

Comment: Ohhh yes, that's definitely a GPU thing. Have you tried it in an older version of Chrome?

Comment: I'm running Chrome version 13.0.782.13, a release version. I see distortions but of a different type than yours. Most letters render properly but others are randomly messed up. Screenshot is here: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D62078_717350_6479958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on "GPU Accelerated Canvas 2D" fixed my Cufon font problem with chrome.  I'm guessing that I must have turned it off.

Thanks for the tip guys.